# How do I concatenate two lists inside nested list Python?

Tags: python, nested-lists

How do I concatenate two lists inside the nested list Python?

I have this list

```
lists_of_lists =[[[1],[2]],[[3],[5]],[[6],[6]]]
```

And my expected output is

```
lists_of_lists =[[1,2],[3,5],[6,6]]
```

I tried this way

```
new = []
lists_of_lists =[[[1],[2]],[[3],[5]],[[6],[6]]]
for i in range(len(lists_of_lists)):
    for list in  lists_of_lists[i]:
        for element in list:
            new.append(element)
print(new)
```

But I got

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 6]
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: Related: [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/4518341)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`operator.concat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.concat) to group 2 separate lists into one and [`itertools.starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) to iterate over main list and unpack inner lists:

```
from operator import concat
from itertools import starmap

result = list(starmap(concat, lists_of_lists))
```

You can do it also without imports using built-in [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function and `lambda` expression *<s>(but why?)</s>*:

```
result = list(map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1], lists_of_lists))
```

You can also use [`chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

result = list(map(list, map(chain.from_iterable, lists_of_lists)))
```

But if you want want to patch code you've written to work as you expected:

```
lists_of_lists =[[[1],[2]],[[3],[5]],[[6],[6]]]
new = []
for sub_list in lists_of_lists:
    new_item = []
    for item in sub_list:
        for element in item:
           new_item.append(element)
    new.append(new_item)
```

Comment: 2 times faster than all the suggested solutions. +1.

Answer (score 3):

```
[[i for inner in sub_lists for i in inner] for sub_lists in lists_of_lists]

# [[1, 2], [3, 5], [6, 6]]
```

Comment: This technique is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/4518341)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

```
[sum(i,[]) for i in lists_of_lists]
```

---

```
[[1, 2], [3, 5], [6, 6]]
```

---

Some `timeit` analysis on the suggested solutions (python 3.7 and windows 10)

Benchmarking list =`[[[1],[2]],[[3],[5]],[[6],[6]]]`

```
In [48]: timeit [sum(i,[]) for i in lists_of_lists]
914 ns ± 103 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [49]: timeit [[i for inner in sub_lists for i in inner] for sub_lists in lists_of_lists]
1.25 µs ± 136 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [64]: timeit list(starmap(concat, lists_of_lists))
639 ns ± 30 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [70]: timeit list(map(list, map(chain.from_iterable, lists_of_lists)))
1.55 µs ± 57 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Benchmarking list = `l=[[[1],[2]],[[3],[5]],[[6],[6]]]*1000000` (3 million).

```
In [60]: timeit [sum(i,[]) for i in l]
1.06 s ± 68 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [61]: timeit [[i for i in j] for j in l]
1.13 s ± 64.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [65]: timeit list(starmap(concat, l))
595 ms ± 15.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [71]: timeit list(map(list, map(chain.from_iterable, l)))
1.39 s ± 101 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: This technique is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952946/4518341)

Comment: Could you add options I've offered in your test?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Actually im running your code right now ;) will add it in minute.

Comment: @Ch3steR, thanks, cause I have no opportunity right now :)

Comment: @OlvinRoght Dude your solution is 2 times faster than my solution and r.ook's

Comment: @Ch3steR, actually that's what I expected, cause `itertools` is as native as it can be.

Comment: @OlvinRoght This solution is a lot slower `result = list(map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1], lists_of_lists))`. I don't remember where I read but It's pretty old stackoverflow answer where it's mentioned `map with lambda` is slower.

Comment: @Ch3steR, yes that's why I added text in parentheses :D You can try to boost a bit your solution by using [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) instead of list comprehension.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I'm surprised by these results. `list(map(list, map(chain.from_iterable, lists_of_lists)))` is slower than map with lambda. Don't what made it slower.

Comment: @Ch3steR, it's because casting result into a list every iteration. I have sorted all solutions by expected productivity and now you confirmed that I have had correct expectations :)

Comment: @Ch3steR, just for fun, test this `list(map(partial(sum, start=[]), lists_of_lists))`. It's your solution but with functional coding style.

Comment: @OlvinRoght It raised `TypeError` saying `sum() takes no keyword arguments`.

Comment: @Ch3steR, weird, cause I have just launched this code in my console. And [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) says that it does take this keyword argument. Python 3.8, btw.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I ran tests on python3.7

Comment: @Ch3steR, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Try `numpy`:

In:

```
import numpy as np
lists_of_lists =np.array([[[1],[2]],[[3],[5]],[[6],[6]]])
lists_of_lists.reshape(lists_of_lists.size//2, 2)
```

Out:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 5],
       [6, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
for subList in lists_of_lists:
    newList = []
    for subSubList in subList:
        newList.extend(subSubList)
    result.append(newList)
```

And `result` contains what is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is readable

```
lists_of_lists =[[[1],[2]],[[3],[5]],[[6],[6]]]

def concat_inner(arr):
    return arr[0]+ arr[1]

final_list = list(map(concat_inner, lists_of_lists))

print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going completely to the low level. Just go one level less deep and flatten the list there.

```
lists_of_lists =[[[1],[2]],[[3],[5]],[[6],[6]]]
for i in lists_of_lists:
    flat_list = [item for sublist in i for item in sublist]
    new.append(flat_list)
print(new)
```